# Prove that every zero of $z^{4}-5z+1$ has multiplicity 1

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$ I need to prove $z^{4}-5z+1$ has only zeros with multiplicity one "with minimal calculation". I've tried using the argument principle, but that requires me to find a curve that surrounds every zero. The only other thing I can think of is proving that $z^{4}-5z+1$ can only be a product of degree 1 irreducible polynomials but that doesn't seem like "minimal calculation". Are there any quick ways of solving this?

Comment: any multiple root would mean that $\gcd (f(z),f'(z))$ was non-trivial.  Is it?

Comment: Similarly, in this particular case it's easy to calculate the zeros of $f'(z)$, and then calculate that none of them are also zeros of $f(z)$.

Comment: @RobertStuckey Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A double (or worse) root would be a root of the derivative, too, but 
$$ 4f(z)-z f'(z) = 4-15 z $$
only vanishes at $z=\frac{4}{15}$, which is not a root for $f'(z)$. It follows that $f(z)$ and $f'(z)$ do not share any root, i.e. that all the roots of $f(z)$ are simple.

---

The idea above does not come out of the blue: it actually is the first step in the computation of a [Sturm chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$f'(z)=4z^3-5=0\implies z=\left(\frac54\right)^\frac13\implies z_1=\left(\frac54\right)^\frac13,z_2=\left(\frac54\right)^\frac13e^{\frac23\pi i},z_3=\left(\frac54\right)^\frac13e^{\frac43\pi i}$$

and

$$z_1^{4}-5z_1+1=-3z_1^4+1=-3\left(\frac54\right)^\frac43+1\neq 0$$

$$z_2^{4}-5z_2+1=-3z_2^4+1=-3\left(\frac54\right)^\frac43e^{\frac83\pi i}+1\neq 0$$

$$z_3^{4}-5z_3+1=-3z_3^4+1=-3\left(\frac54\right)^\frac43e^{\frac{16}3\pi i}+1\neq 0$$

Comment: Actually you can "*keep it real*".

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio because the complex roots are conjugate and thus distinct?

Comment: Because $4 f(z)-z f'(z)$ is linear: see my solution above.

Comment: @gimusi Also because $\,z^3 = 5/4 \implies z^4-5z+1=(5/4  - 5)z+1\,$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Ah I see now, at first I can't follow your reasoning. Nice trick!

Comment: @dxiv Got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alt. hint: the polynomial has no negative real roots, and $0$ or $2$ positive ones by the [rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs). Since $p(0) \gt 0$ and $p(1) \lt 0$ it has in fact two positive roots, one less than $1$ and the other greater than $1$, thus distinct. The remaining two (non-real) complex roots must also be distinct (*why?*).

Answer (score 0):

Assume $a\in \mathbb C$ is (at least) a double root of the given polynomial $f(z) = z^4-5z+1$. Then $a$ is also a root of $f'(z) = 4z^3-5$. We need to get a quick contradiction. From
$$
0=\Big(a^4-5a+1\Big)-a\cdot\frac 14\Big(4a^3-5\Big)=-\frac {15}4a+1
$$
we get $a=4/15$, which is not a root (of $f'$).

**Note:**

Using a computational aid, [sage](http://www.sagemath.org):

```
sage: R.<z> = PolynomialRing(QQ)
sage: f = z^4 -5*z +1
sage: # f has multiple roots iff its discriminant vanishes, but...
sage: f.discriminant()
-16619
sage: # The roots are approximatively...
sage: f.roots(QQbar, multiplicities=False)
[0.2003220662079570?,
 1.637305775417577?,
 -0.9188139208127669? - 1.484812643834945?*I,
 -0.9188139208127669? + 1.484812643834945?*I]
```

(I had to insert something new, since too many answers and comments were giving the same computation, so all humans think humanly, all computers computationally...)

Comment: I gave a slow contradiction

Answer (score 0):

Relatively prime with its derivative

$$  \left(   x^{4}  - 5 x  + 1 \right)  $$

$$  \left(  4 x^{3}  - 5 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{4}  - 5 x  + 1 \right)  =  \left(  4 x^{3}  - 5 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  x  }{ 4 }  \right) } +  \left(   \frac{  - 15 x  + 4 }{ 4 }  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(  4 x^{3}  - 5 \right)  =  \left(   \frac{  - 15 x  + 4 }{ 4 }  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 3600 x^{2}  - 960 x  - 256 }{ 3375 }  \right) } +  \left( \frac{ -16619}{3375 } \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   \frac{  - 15 x  + 4 }{ 4 }  \right)  =  \left( \frac{ -16619}{3375 } \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 50625 x  - 13500 }{ 66476 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  x  }{ 4 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  x  }{ 4 }  \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 3600 x^{2}  - 960 x  - 256 }{ 3375 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  - 900 x^{3}  - 240 x^{2}  - 64 x  + 3375 }{ 3375 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{  - 3600 x^{2}  - 960 x  - 256 }{ 3375 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 50625 x  - 13500 }{ 66476 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  - 3375 x^{4}  + 16875 x  - 3375 }{ 16619 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{  - 13500 x^{3}  + 16875 }{ 16619 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{4}  - 5 x  + 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{  - 3600 x^{2}  - 960 x  - 256 }{ 16619 }  \right)  -  \left(  4 x^{3}  - 5 \right)  \left(   \frac{  - 900 x^{3}  - 240 x^{2}  - 64 x  + 3375 }{ 16619 }  \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  $$

........